# In which directory should I save my loadable module so that it can be permanently loaded?

Tags: drivers, kernel

I want to permanently load a loadable module in the Linux kernel. I have tried to do it by editing my `/etc/modules` file, but I'm unsure as to where I should place my module for Ubuntu to find it on reboot.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.10. I currently get an error when Ubuntu is loading `failed to load kernel modules`. I currently have my module in a folder in my Desktop directory. It is compiled properly and I have the `.ko` file in my directory.

Comment: what exactly did you put in `/etc/modules`? The full path? Kernel modules are in the directories in `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)` but I am not sure how to do this correctly.

Comment: No i just added the name of the module as it was suggested in an answer to a similar question. Should i add the full path?

Comment: Either that or try placing the module somewhere in `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel` (choose a directory that looks appropriate for whatever your module does) and leave `/etc/modules` as is. If neither work, then you need to do something more complex!

Comment: I'll get back to you in a bit after trying both. Thanks

Comment: Hmm hope it helps - Good luck! If it does work, you can post an answer to your own question

Comment: It doesn't let me copy my folder to the directory you listed even with root privileges. And giving the whole path in the /etc/modules file also didn't work. Is there any other way?

Comment: I have no trouble writing to that directory with `sudo` - how exactly are you doing it?

Comment: `sudo cp ~/Desktop/kernell /lib/modules/4.8.0-34-generic/kernel`

Comment: is `~/Desktop/kernell` a directory?

Comment: Yes, its the folder where I have my .ko file. I had to rename it to 'kernell' from 'kernel' because there is already a folder named 'kernel' in the directory you asked me to copy it to.

Comment: in which case you need to use `cp -r`

Comment: Damn! yes it is copied now but still not loading. Can it be that there is something wrong with my module? It compiles fine though

Comment: I really don't know what you need to do but I did kind of suspect it would not be as simple as dropping it into the right location... Maybe you could look into [DKMS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DKMS) and kernel documentation

Comment: Not sure myself but I think you need to use `sudo /sbin/insmod <pathto>/module_name` [to load a module], and `sudo /sbin/rmmod module_name` [to remove a module]...

Comment: did you ever get it figured out?